# Issues with Editor role and custom menu page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom menu item in my WordPress admin section to allow for the setting of a number.

This menu it is visible by my editors, but when they attempt to update the field, they are greeted with a message that says they are not allowed to manage these options.

Here is a rough breakdown of the script:

```
<?php
if(is_admin()){
  add_action( 'admin_menu', 'progress_menu' );
}

function progress_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'Progress Bar', 'Progress Bar', 'edit_pages', __FILE__, 'progress_page', 'dashicons-admin-generic' );
  add_action( 'admin_init', 'progress_register' );
}

function progress_register() {
  register_setting( 'my-site', 'progress' );
}

function progress_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Progress Bar</h2>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'my-site' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'my-site' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Progress</th>
        <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="progress" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('progress') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php submit_button(); ?>

</form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Any thoughts why my users with the editor role are unable to update this?

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/#notes):

> If you are using the Settings API to save data, and need the user to
> be other than the administrator, you need to modify the permissions
> via the hook
> [`option_page_capability_{$option_group}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/option_page_capability_option_page/),
> where `$option_group` is the same as `$option_group` in
> [`register_setting()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/).

So basically, just use the example on that page and simply change the `option_page_capability_my-options-group` to `option_page_capability_my-site`. I.e.

```php
// Modify capability - allow non admins to save the options.
function wpdocs_my_page_capability( $capability ) {
    return 'edit_others_posts'; // or edit_pages if you want
}
// you used register_setting( 'my-site', 'progress' ), so use my-site in the 1st parameter
add_filter( 'option_page_capability_my-site', 'wpdocs_my_page_capability' );
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the bounty, but could you please accept my answer, if it answered your question? 